# Selecting Image Is Greyed Out - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xcode

I am trying to find what the issue is with this. When I go to select a photo everything on my phone is greyed out. Any ideas? and yes I have my permission set up correctly.

```
private EditText userName, userPassword, userEmail, userAge;
private Button regButton;
private TextView userLogin;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private ImageView userProfilePic;
String email, name, age, password;
private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
private static int PICK_IMAGE = 123;
Uri imagePath;
private StorageReference storageReference;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data.getData() != null){
        imagePath = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imagePath);
            userProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Full activity

```
package com.technicalpixels.busybuddiepav10;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private EditText userName, userPassword, userEmail, userAge;
private Button regButton;
private TextView userLogin;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private ImageView userProfilePic;
String email, name, age, password;
private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
private static int PICK_IMAGE = 123;
Uri imagePath;
private StorageReference storageReference;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data.getData() != null){
        imagePath = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imagePath);
            userProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
    setupUIViews();

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference();

    userProfilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("images/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), PICK_IMAGE);
        }
    });



    regButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(validate()){
                //Upload data to the database
                String user_email = userEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String user_password = userPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_email, user_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            sendEmailVerification();
                            sendUserData();
                            firebaseAuth.signOut();
                            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Successfully Registered, Upload complete!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Registration Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    userLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });

}

private void setupUIViews(){
    userName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    userPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserPassword);
    userEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserEmail);
    regButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    userLogin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvUserLogin);
    userAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etAge);
    userProfilePic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivProfile);
}

private Boolean validate(){
    Boolean result = false;

    name = userName.getText().toString();
    password = userPassword.getText().toString();
    email = userEmail.getText().toString();
    age = userAge.getText().toString();


    if(name.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty() || age.isEmpty() || imagePath == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter all the details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}


private void sendEmailVerification(){
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if(firebaseUser!=null){
        firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    sendUserData();
                    Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Successfully Registered, Verification mail sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    firebaseAuth.signOut();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Verification mail has'nt been sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

  private void sendUserData(){
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());
    StorageReference imageReference = storageReference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Images").child("Profile Pic");  //User id/Images/Profile Pic.jpg
    UploadTask uploadTask = imageReference.putFile(imagePath);
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Upload failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Upload successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile(age, email, name);
    myRef.setValue(userProfile);
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have any error in your logcat

Comment: E/EnhancedIntentService: binding to the service failed

Comment: share your image picker activity

Comment: I don't have one.

Comment: so you have only main activity? show me that

Comment: I have multiple but this is the only one that uses a picture selector,

Comment: I attached it to the main portion

Answer (score 0):

Tried your code:

Replace with this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
```

Comment: What all do i take out?

Comment: Everything in your onClick. Replace all those intent lines with the above code